# SQL Order By Custom Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a data in this order

```
Id   Value
--   ----
1    a
1    b
1    c
2    a
2    c
3    b
4    c
4    b
4    a
```

I want to sort data in this order

```
Id   Value
--   ----
1    a
2    a
3    b
4    c
1    b
2    c
4    b
1    c
4    a
```

Comment: and what's the logic behind that sort?

Comment: Don't just post your expected order and expect people to *deduce* the logic. We don't charge by the word here, so add plenty more of them to your question.

Comment: Great, thanks for telling us. Good luck! Don't forget to post an answer when you work out how to do this, and explain the logic behind it.

Comment: Please post your attempts on what are trying to do.

Comment: Actually there are multiple records in table with same Ids. But when I need to fetch them and display on page, all unique Ids data should be displayed in first batch and so on.

Comment: The only id you have that's unique is 3, the others have multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to intersperse the numbers.  For this purpose, you can use `row_number()`:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by value),
         id
```

Comment: This does produce something very similar to what the OP asks for, other than the `a,c` values paired with `4`s.